# Install multiple user accounts on kitkat 4.4.2

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, installation, multi-user

I have an Azpen A1040 and it did not come with the ability to have multiple device user accounts, which is less than desired because this tablet is shared in my household.

I rooted my tablet, but I am not sure how to install or enable that feature.

Answer (score 4):

Some phones and tablets do not have the multiple user feature, which means that this feature is disabled by manufacturer. The feature can be enabled by installing "Multi Users for Phone" module on Xposed Framework, which needs root. This works for Tablets too, and works for Android 4.4.2 KitKat (I am not sure if it works on other versions).

**Steps on how to do this:**

1. Root device (Required)
2. Backup data (Recommended)
3. Download Xposed Installer
4. Install Xposed Framework
5. Go to Modules and search "Multiuser"
6. It listes "Multi Users for phone" in "Not Installed" Category, click that
7. Swipe left to Versions and download the latest version
8. Install the Module, Activate and Reboot

Tada! To edit Users, go to Settings and Users.